# Error message in REST webservices

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am calling REST webservices from JSP using AJAX . Can you tell me the best way to send custom error message from REST webservice to JSP ?

Comment: How can we tell solution without any code?

Comment: the answer is dependant on the techstack you are using

Answer (score 1):

Consider using HTTP response codes with (possibly) json response bodies to supply any required information so the client application can react accordingly.

Comment: 1)I am asking about Exception mapper , Is using Exception mapper is correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [WebapplicationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html). You can give it the Errorcode (also custom ones) and a body for the response. You could use the JSON Format if you have a complex structure to display your errors but i would suggest just using the an errormessage (for example in case of a bad request, what part of the request was bad).

Comment: 1)I am asking about Exception mapper , Is using Exception mapper is  correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JAX-RS REST webservice, you can configure Spring `@Controller`. Your method should produce `application/json` and return `Response` object, like in this example:

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getUserById(@PathParam("id") String userId) {

        // Here your logic

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setMsg("Bad Request");
        foo.setData("User " + userId + " not found")

        return Response.status(400).entity(foo).build();
    }
```

And from AJAX, you can catch error message

```
// Get user details
$.getJSON(encodeURI("./rest/user/get/" + userId), function(data) {

    // Some logic on success

    // Fail
}).fail( function(jqxhr) {
    console.log(jqxhr.responseJSON.msg);
});
```

Comment: 1)I am asking about Exception mapper , Is using Exception mapper is correct approach?

Comment: Well, exceptions are used to be thrown when actions are not controlled by you (like object types, permissions, syntax). But for REST services, you need to validate manually the input data and return "warning" message, like wrong number, string, value... I use Exception mapper only to log on server errors occured during requests...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways. 
1. You can look at the response status you receive from the web service. The statuses starting with 2** are a success response (Eg: 200, 201), the ones starting with 4** or 5** are errors.

2. But the optimal way to handle and track exceptions is to use ExceptionMapper. You can write your own class that implements ExceptionMapper like below:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable arg0) {

   return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
           .entity("Custom Exception: Error retrieving data")
           .build();
   }

   }
   ```

You can write your own custom exceptions like below or can throw blanket exception like below. The above approach is the preferred one though.

```
 @Provider
 public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(Throwable arg0) {

    return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity("Custom Exception: Error retrieving data")
            .build();
}

}
```